# Does Nondetection block all Divination magic or only scrying?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

In 5e, the wording of the spell is "The target can't be targeted by **any divination magic** or perceived through magical scrying sensors." Does this mean that Divination spells such as Guidance don't have any affect on the target? Can the target still *cast* Divination spells and receive their benefits, such as Comprehend Languages?

Comment: Welcome to the stack! I’ve closed this question because it has been asked before. This is not a problem, duplicates can serve to signpost existing questions and answers. While you’re here, take the [tour] and visit the [help] for more info about the site.